# On what platform is func(shared_ptr(...), shared_ptr(...)) really dangerous?

Tags: c++, constructor, shared-ptr, operator-precedence

I remember that Scott Meyers taught me that

```
func(shared_ptr(new P), shared_ptr(new Q));
```

is dangerous, because (if I remember correctly) the **order** of *memory allocation*, *reference counting* (constructing) and assignment to *function parameters* **allows a [leak](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)** (theoretically?) to appear in rare circumstances. To prevent this one should encapsulate the `shared_ptr` in a function call, e.g. in `make_shared()`.

```
func(make_shared<P>(), make_shared<Q>());
```

Here is some [discussion](http://herbsutter.com/2012/01/20/gotw-103-smart-pointers-part-1-difficulty-310/) about it, too.

I would like to know if there are (current) compilers **in the field**, on certain systems **that indeed may leave some hole** in some error cases? Or are those times gone, or were they only theoretical, anyway?

Most interesting would be know if any of these have that issue:

- g++ 4.x or g++ 2.95, on Linux i386, x64, ARM, m68k or any Windows
- Visual C++ on i368, x64 or ARM
- Clang/LLVM on Linux, or any of its platforms
- How about C++ compilers on/from Sun or IBM, HP-UX?

Has anyone observed this behavior on his specific platform?

Comment: **Note**: To would-be answerers; the OP is aware of the potential leak, so further references to why it *could* leak are futile. The question is specific: *did anyone witnessed it* ?

Comment: Well, I've never encountered an actual problem because of this, because I'd never write it in the first place.  Any compiler doing any degree of optimization may break this code in specific cases.  (Finding which cases is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Which is a poor question, since if one is aware of the potential leak, one doesn't write such code, and so one won't witness it.  What is certain is that the problem isn't theoretical, because compilers _do_ reorder code in ways that would break the first example.  It's part of the standard optimization techniques, used by practically every compiler.

Comment: I would point that relying on the absence of use of this optimization is hazardous. This leads to massive breakdowns of software such as what happened when gcc 4.7 introduced a more aggressive reuse of stack space allocated for temporaries => many programs who relied on temporaries leaving longer than the Standard guaranteed suddenly broke down (in sometimes mysterious ways).

Comment: @JamesKanze: I am aware of optimizations techniques, but I must admit I never witnessed the issue. I have seen many optimizations hampered by the presence of exceptions, for example, and I do not know whether this is the case here (or not). Certainly, even if today it works, it is unreliable.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I've never witnessed the issue either, because I've never written such code.  Exceptions do have an impact; the compiler cannot schedule one of the `operator new` in parallel with the other constructor, for example (unless it can prove that interrupting the constructor with an exception that it doesn't expect cannot cause any problems).  But the order `new P`, `new Q`, construct first `shared_ptr`, construct second `shared_ptr` is clearly legal, and I'm fairly sure that g++ or Sun CC will use it in some particular cases.

Comment: I've never seen this before. It can allocate Q, then P, which throws, but Q never made it into a shared_ptr, and so leaks?

Comment: Is this the same for unique_ptr or smart pointer in general, or specific to shared_ptr?

Comment: @MatthieuM. refering to *"gcc 4.7 introduced a more aggressive reuse of stack"*: I would be interested in a concrete example of a program that worked on gcc <4.7 and crashed >=4.7. Has someone boiled that down to a small demo program, maybe? I'd like to try. As an additional demonstration to the non-learners why `T& operator+(T&, T&)` is evil, for e.g ;-)

Comment: @NeilKirk: It's the same for any kind of "smart pointer" or RAII container in general. This is why `make_unique` should make it into C++1y afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func(shared_ptr(new P), shared_ptr(new Q));
```

A C++ compiler is free to implement this in the following order:

1. new Q
2. new P
3. construct shared_ptr around allocated P
4. construct shared_ptr around allocated Q
5. call func

(A compiler can perform 1, 2, 3, and 4 in any order, as long as 1 is before 4 and 2 before 3).

In the order above, if `P`'s constructor or the call to `new` throws, `Q` is a memory leak (memory is allocated but the `shared_ptr` is not yet constructed around it).

As such, you should call `std::make_shared` (which handles exceptions on allocation gracefully), and you know that when `std::make_shared` has returned for one of them, the `shared_ptr` is fully constructed and will not leak.

> I would like to know if there are (current) compilers in the field, on certain systems that indeed may leave some hole in some error cases?

All standards compliant compilers will have this behavior.

Comment: Would a compiler be standard compliant that implements the order *1,4,2,3,5* and would that solve the problem? First, doing all `Q`-work, then all `P`-work?

Comment: Yes, it would be compliant, but a compiler doesn't know what a shared_ptr is (other than a class). It doesn't know that it should create smart pointers before anything else.

Comment: @utnapistim: The OP is aware of the issue, the question is about whether it is theoretical or if some compilers do exhibit the behavior (and which).

Comment: @MatthieuM. This answer is quite specific about that - it is *not* theoretical, and any fully-compliant compiler will exhibit the behaviour. Are you downvoting based on that?

Comment: @SteveL: I too love Standard compliance, however the OP did not ask whether the Standard allowed it (he knows it does), but asked whether someone knew of a compiler that exhibited this behavior. The answer here says that all standard compliant compilers *may* exhibit the behavior, which is certainly true, but falls short of answering the question asked.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I could not said it better, Thanks. Indeed I know about the Why's and Dont's, but wanted to know if there one could implement a compiler with a "safe mode" -- or if that one then would not be standard compliant anymore.

Comment: @towi: Look at [-fstack-reuse](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) code generation option in GCC. It was introduced to forbid the optimization and present a simple example.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a platform problem, it's an exception-safety issue. So the answer to your actual question is: *all* those platforms might exhibit the issue.

The memory leak problem arises due to 2 things:

- Allocating memory with `new` might throw `bad_alloc`
- The order in which arguments to functions are evaluated is unspecified.

The docs for `boost::shared_ptr` capture it nicely [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#BestPractices)

There is more treatment in detail on the general problem [here (GOTW)](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/056.htm)

The reason it might be "rare" comes about because it's really not that common to get `bad_alloc`, but your code must handle the possibility safely if it is to avoid memory leaks.

(I say "might" exhibit it - I haven't checked that they all throw `bad_alloc` if `new` fails...)

Comment: Not only `bad_alloc` of `new` is be problematic, but **any exception** thrown in the constructors `P()` or `Q()`, correct? So, depending on the implemented evaluation order of the function arguments, I would observe the memory leak in one of both cases, always? This would mean that the *"unspecifiedness" of function arguments* does not have anything to do with it -- it could be specified to, say, left-to-right and then I would observe the leak, still. Wouldn't I? I seem to remember that it is rather the *"unspecifiedness" of alloc/new/param*, and I wonder if "the right order" could remedy it.

Comment: Your answer is nice, but off-topic. The OP is aware of the issue already and asks on which compilers/platforms it was witnessed.

Comment: @towi - you're right - any exception during construction of either could provoke it. The evaluation order being unspecified means that a compliant implementation can evaluate them in any order it likes as long as they're all /completely/ evaluated when the function body is entered. Tying this down to one specified order would remove an important optimisation point, and possibly make it difficult for some platforms to implement it at all.

Answer (score 0):

because both `new` operation will be done first, and then they are passed into `shared_ptr`'s constructor, but which `shared_ptr` constructs first is unspecified, so one of the newly created object may cause a memory leak.

Comment: This sounds factual. Is this always "the order of things"? Or only "one possible order", and could another order prevent this leak?

Comment: @towi Many different orderings are possible, and which ordering will depend on the compiler, the options used to invoke it, and the surrounding context (how many registers are available, etc.).  About all you can say is that most, if not all compilers will use an order which breaks the first line in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is unsafe on any platform which has a reordering optimizer, if that optimizer performs the following optimization `A;B;A;B => A;A;B;B`. This optimization improves code cache efficiency, so in general that's a good idea.

Obviously that optimizer can only rearrange B and A if their relative order is unspecified, which happens to be the case here.